# SFTP to multiple machines in single command

Tags: shell-script, sftp

I want a single SFTP command to transfer one file to two machines. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No. An SFTP command is happening on a single connection.

This sounds very much like you want some simple program that takes a list of target computers, and copies files to/from these, executes commands, checks state and success, consistently.

There's many such tools! What I use is usually use is [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/getting_started/index.html).

Essentially, you would write a file that just gives a name to your group of two machines. Let's call it `inventory.ini`:

```ini
[karthiksmachines]
machine1
machine2
```

(of course, replacing `machine1` and `machine2` with the host names or IP addresses of your machines)

Then you test whether that works simply by running:

```bash
ansible -i inventory.ini karthiksmachines -m ping
```

You should get a nice output that says `machine1 | SUCCESS =>…` and the same for `machine2`. (If not, you probably haven't set up ssh access keys correctly.)

If that works, great! Now let's write a *playbook*, i.e. a collection of tasks to do on each machine. Let's call this file `playbook.yaml`.

```yaml
- name: Maintain the machines of Karthik
  hosts: karthiksmachines
  tasks:
   - name: Copy file over
     ansible.builtin.copy:
       src: /path/to/your/local/file.ext
       dest: /path/where/the/file/should/end/file.ext
```

As you can guess, you can add more tasks to the `tasks:` list; often these are things like installing security updates, downloading log files, or setting up services on the servers. Whatever!

You then run that playbook:

```bash
ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini playbook.yaml
```

So, there it is. Once you put the machines you want to take care of into a file, and the instructions what you want these machines to go through into a another file, it's a single command you need to run :)

I find that easy enough that I try to do it for all things I do with all my servers, especially things like software installation, service configuration, user creation ….
That has the big advantage that if I need to add another server, I just add it to the inventory and let the playbook run. Reproducible servers!